# Learn Python the Hard Way, Ex 49 : Comparing objects using assert_equal

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is it possible to use assert_equal to compare objects? I keep seeing this error:

```
AssertionError: <ex49.parser.Sentence object at 0x01F1BAF0> !=
<ex49.parser.Sentence object at 0x01F1BB10>
```

The relevant code fragment:

```
def test_parse_subject():

    testsentence = "princess go east"
    result = lexicon.scan(testsentence)
    Sent = parse_sentence(result)
    ResultSent = Sentence(('subject', 'princess'),
                      ('verb', 'go'),
                      ('object', 'east'))
    print ResultSent.subject
    print ResultSent.verb
    print ResultSent.object
    print Sent.subject
    print Sent.verb
    print Sent.object
    assert_equal(Sent, ResultSent)
```

The print outputs on screen suggests that the objects have the same contents - yet the assertion error shows up. Why is this? Is there some way to use assert_equal to override this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to implement the __eq__ method on the Sentence class.

> assertEqual(first, second, msg=None)¶
>   Test that first and second are equal. If the values do not compare equal, the test will fail.
>
> In addition, if first and second are the exact same type and one of list, tuple, dict, set, frozenset or unicode or any type that a subclass registers with addTypeEqualityFunc() the type-specific equality function will be called in order to generate a more useful default error message (see also the list of type-specific methods).

[Python unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html)

> The correspondence between operator symbols and method names is as follows: xlt(y), x<=y calls x.**le**(y), x==y calls x.**eq**(y), x!=y and x<>y call x.**ne**(y), x>y calls x.**gt**(y), and x>=y calls x.**ge**(y).

[Python data model documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

An example:

```
import unittest


class A:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num == other.num


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        a1 = A(1)
        a12 = A(1)
        a2 = A(2)

        self.assertEqual(a1, a1, 'a1 != a1')
        self.assertEqual(a1, a12, 'a1 != a12')
        self.assertEqual(a1, a2, 'a1 != a2')

def main():
    unittest.TestRunner(Test())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now comment the __eq__ method and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is good info, For me, I was too lazy to search so I just compared the variables of the two objects as below:

```
def test_parse_subject():
    word_list_a = lexicon.scan("eat the bear")
    Sentence1 = Sentence(('noun','player'),('verb', 'eat'),('noun', 'bear'))
    Sentence2 = parse_subject(word_list_a,('noun','player'))

    assert_equal(Sentence2.subject, Sentence1.subject)  
    assert_equal(Sentence2.verb, Sentence1.verb)
    assert_equal(Sentence2.object, Sentence1.object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am working through LPTHW ex49.  Specifically for the context of this example, I was able to get it to work by adding the __eq__() method to the Sentence class, as follows:

```
Class Sentence(object):

    def __init__(self, subject, verb, object_)
        ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.subject == other.subject and
                self.verb == other.verb and
                self.object_ == other.object_)
```

Then, in the test file, I did:

```
# where LIST5 is defined above to give list of two tuples, [('verb', 'go'), ('direction', 'east')]
def test_parse_subject():
    wordlist = list(LIST5) 
    sent = parse.Sentence(('noun', 'person'), ('verb'), ('go'), ('direction', 'east))
    newsent = parse.parse_subject(wordlist, ('noun', 'person'))
    assert_equal(newsent, sent)
```

As far as I can tell (new to this), assert_equal with nose and unittest will call the __eq__() method if it exists.  In this case, the test is OK as long as the two objects have the same three values for subject, verb, object_.  However, this took me a while to figure out, because I had a bug in my code, and the only thing nose would provide is the same error message that you received, even when I had the __eq__() method.  That is, it provided "AssertionError: ...object at 0x... != ... object at 0x..."  This misled me into thinking that the __eq__() method was not working, since it looked like it was comparing addresses.  Not sure if there's a better way to do this.

NOTE: I renamed object to object_ because gedit was highlighting object as a python keyword.  Not sure if this is recommended to use trailing underscore.