# AssertionError when trying to assert return value from two dictionaries with py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, assert

I'm testing a text-based game I've been making to learn Python. The last few days I have been busy finding a solution for a problem I keep encountering. I have tried multiple test methods, but they all end up giving me the same error.

The problem is the following AssertionError (using `py.test`):

```
 E       AssertionError: assert <Textgame.Waffle.WineFields object at 0x03BDECD0> == 
 <Textgame.Waffle.WineFields object at 0x03BD00D0>
```

Obviously, the object (`Textgame.Waffle.WineFields`) is correct, but the location is different. I don't care about the location. I assume this is because I'm using two separate dictionaries with the same contents. However, I would prefer to keep using this dictionary if possible.

The minimal working example of the test looks as follows:

```
import Textgame.Waffle

def test_change_map():

    roomnames = {
        "the wine fields" : Textgame.Waffle.WineFields(),
    }

    room = "the wine fields"
    next_room = roomnames[room]

    assert Textgame.Waffle.Map(room).change(room) == next_room
```

The Textgame.Waffle game I'm trying to assert looks like this:

```
class WineFields(object):
    pass

class Map(object):

    roomnames = {
        'the wine fields': WineFields(),
    }

    def __init__(self, next_one):
        self.next_one = next_one

    def change(self, next_one):
        return Map.roomnames[next_one]
```

I have tried some methods to solve this, for example using

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.next_one == other.next
```

inside the Map class, but either I placed it wrong or I should not be using it for this problem at all. I got this idea from another StackOverflow page on roughly the same problem:

[Learn Python the Hard Way, Ex 49 : Comparing objects using assert_equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306242/learn-python-the-hard-way-ex-49-comparing-objects-using-assert-equal/11732234#11732234)

Could someone please explain to me how I can assert that the output I get is what I expect, and not worry about whether the location is the same?

Comment: You seem to be using two different instances of `WineFields` and expect them to be the same. You need to add attributes which will have equal value and add an `__eq__` method to the `WineFields` class as the other problem does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learn Python the Hard Way, Ex 49 : Comparing objects using assert\_equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306242/learn-python-the-hard-way-ex-49-comparing-objects-using-assert-equal)

Comment: Thank you, @quamrana. The problem was the location of the __eq__ method. I had not understood that it should be in the `WineFields` class. not in the `Map` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to identify each instance:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x
```

This will mean that constructing them will need a parameter:

```
one = X(1)
other = X(1)
one == other
```

The two different instances will equate to each other due to the member `x` being equal.

In fact I've just replicated the accepted answer in the question you [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306640/4834)